# Will Changing Home Directory Name Mess Up Virtual Environments?

Tags: python, macos, virtualenv

I was going to change the home directory name on my MacBook, but I was wondering if that will mess up any virtual environments or any other files I'm not thinking of right now in my already created Python/Django projects?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to find out is to set up a test, duplicate account with all the same setup (.login, .bashrc, .bash_profile, .tcshrc, etc.) and see what happens when you try.

You may be perfectly fine, or you might have your home directory name hard coded into one of those files, in which case testing this out first might show the problem really quickly (before you mess up your real home directory).

Answer (score 0):

Rename the home directory, then create a link pointing the old directory name to the new directory name.

This way, anything that points to the old name will still work.